# How to use the jpstat package of R?

Tags: r, api

Everybody!
I am using the **jpstat** package of R, it seems that it is a good program for using the e-Stat API, a portal site for [Japanese government statistics](https://www.e-stat.go.jp/en), and includes functions for automatic query generation, data collection and formatting.

However, when I follow the steps that written in the R-blogger (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jpstat/readme/README.html), it doesn't work! I use my ID to login the website, and get the permission to connect API of the portal site for Japanese Government Statistics. When I return to RStudio to execute those arguments which written in the R-blogger:

```
census <- estat(appId = "My e-Stat appId", 
                statsDataId = "https://www.e-stat.go.jp/dbview?sid=0003410379")
```

then, the result is:

> Error in estat_check_status(.) :
> 認証<U+306B>失敗<U+3057><U+307E><U+3057><U+305F>。<U+30A2><U+30D7><U+30EA><U+30B1><U+30FC><U+30B7><U+30E7><U+30F3>ID<U+3092>確認<U+3057><U+3066>下<U+3055><U+3044>。

Obviously, the website does not allow me to enter the database.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Thanks Rui Barradas for editing my posts!

Answer (score 0):

Everybody!
I have found the ID to access the website of Japanese government statistics successfully after posting the question yesterday.